# Is the Cheeger constant of an induced subgraph of a cube at most 1?

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, sp.spectral-theory

It is known that the
[Cheeger constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheeger_constant_%28graph_theory%29)
of a
[hypercube graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph) $Q_n$
is exactly $1$, regardless of its dimension $n$.  Is $1$ also an upper bound
on the Cheeger constant of nontrivial induced connected subgraphs of $Q_n$?

The Cheeger constant $h(G)$ is also known as the
[edge expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expander_graph#Edge_expansion)
or the isoperimetic number.

To indirectly address a comment,
here are the Cheeger constants of more graphs:
$h($[$Q_n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph)$) = 1$ 
$h($[$P_n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph)$) = 1 / \lfloor n / 2 \rfloor$ 
$h($[$C_n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph)$) = 2 / \lfloor n / 2 \rfloor$ 
$h($[$K_n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph)$) = \lceil n / 2 \rceil$

Comment: Isn't the Cheeger constant of a subgraph always smaller than or equal to the Cheeger constant of a graph?

Comment: @Seva: Consider two copies of the complete graph connected at a single vertex.

Comment: On this occasion: are the Cheeger constants of the discrete tori $C_n^r$ known?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your conjecture is true, every subgraph of the cube has expansion constant at most $1$.

*Proof:* Suppose we are given a subgraph $G\subset Q_n$, $n>1$ and cut the cube into $2$ $(n-1)$-dimensional subcubes $A_1,A_2$. (So that $A_1\cup A_2=Q_n$)  The key is to notice that each vertex in $A_1$ is connected to one and only one vertex in $A_2$.  Then split $G$ into two parts, $G_1=G\cap A_1$ and $G_2=G\cap A_2$. One of these will have size $\leq \frac{|G|}{2}$, suppose it is $G_1$.  Because $G_1$ is in $A_1$, it is only connected to vertices in $A_2$, and we have $\partial G_1 \leq |G_1|$.   Since the expansion constant is the minimum, we conclude that $$h(G)\leq 1.$$